# javascript sql.js giving error Uncaught Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sql.js

Here is my `<script>` tag in my HTML page giving me the error:

Uncaught Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

```
<script>
   var file = "/data/myDB.sqlite";
   var db = new SQL.Database(file);
   db.run("SELECT * FROM WEBUSERS", function(err, rows) {
      rows.forEach(function (row) { 
         console.log('WEBUSERS Created User: '+row.USERNAME);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My Node.js server runs perfectly. I assume this is more a SQL.js issue. 
It is not reading the .sqlite file of mine that already has a DB in it.
I tried .db and .sql too.
The file opens perfectly in SQLBrowser and in the terminal, but not in the web-brower

Comment: The browser doesn't have access to files stored on your PC.

Comment: The web application is hosted locally on 127.0.0.1:8080 and the DB file is inside my htdocs where my html files are hosted...so technically its on the server.

Comment: Apologies, looking at the docs your database needs to be read into an Uint8Array and passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the constructor doesn't take a string, it takes a Uint8Array containing the SQLite database.

One way to do this would be to use an ajax request to get your database as an arraybuffer and transform it into a Uint8Array.

```
var file = "/data/myDB.sqlite";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', file, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    var db = new SQL.Database(data);
    db.run("SELECT * FROM WEBUSERS", function(err, rows) {
        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            console.log('WEBUSERS Created User: ' + row.USERNAME);
        });
    });
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: thanks allot Ben. I'm not getting any errors now, but also it is not logging anything in my console from my query to the DB... any suggestions?

Comment: Also i see it is not accessing the db.run function for some reason

Comment: Sounds like the call to your database is failing. Try logging errors. `xhr.onerror = console.log.bind(console);`

Comment: Getting no errors with that. However when I change my table name to something that dont exist, it does however pick up that the table does not exist.
I'm finding it difficult to return the data from the select statement.

Comment: Any feedback here? I'm still not able to get the data from my query.
Connection to the DB file is successful

Comment: Have you tried logging `err` from your query callback?